# tile image with MATLAB imrotate

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

When I use the `imrotate` function of MATLAB, output image has missing parts which are filled with zeros.

Can I somehow make it so the triangles in the corners (i.e. the missing parts) are filled with the opposite edge of the image? So it will be like I have tiled the image with 8 neighbors around itself, and then rotated and cropped the bigger image?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: "So it will be like ..." - why don't you take this approach, like repeating your image ```I```: ```K = repmat( I, 3, 3 )``` and then cropping the rotated ```K```? Too inefficient? Edit: as you know by which angle you will rotate you could already crop ```K``` the pixels that will never be shown in the resulting image.

Comment: Actually if the image height is way bigger than the image width, and depending on the rotation angle, it might be not enough to repeat the image in a 3x3 tile.

Comment: @BlackAdder yes, I didn't think of that possibility. But luckily in my case the images are square, and the rotation is less than 20 degrees, so we can assume the simplest case :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best (and most memory efficient) way of doing this, would be to use [`interp2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) to sample the original image at the new pixel centers (the original pixel centers "rotated" by the *opposite* of the desired angle). And then to use [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) on these sample points to ensure that they fall within the dimension of the original image. And the added benefit of `mod` is that the new x,y coordinates that are out of range, simply "wrap around" to the other side of the image.

```
% Load some sample image
load mri 
im = double(D(:,:,12));
[rows, cols] = size(im);

% The original pixel centers
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows);

% Setup the rotation matrix
theta = pi/4;
R = [cos(-theta), -sin(-theta);
     sin(-theta), cos(-theta)];

% Center of Rotation (center of the image)
center = [cols/2, rows/2];

% Determine the new pixel centers (rotated)
xy = bsxfun(@minus, [xx(:), yy(:)], center) * R;
xy = bsxfun(@plus, xy, center);

% Mod these using the dimensions of the image to "wrap" around
x = mod(xy(:,1) - 1, cols - 1) + 1;
y = mod(xy(:,2) - 1, rows - 1) + 1;

% Sample the original image at the new pixel centers
im2 = interp2(xx, yy, im, x, y);
im2 = reshape(im2, [rows, cols])
```

**Rotation = 45 degrees**

[image]

This will work with any arbitrary aspect ratio (below is an image demonstrating the issue brought up by [@BlackAdder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261062/blackadder) where a repmat [3,3] wouldn't work due to the image being tall and narrow).

**Rotation = 90 degrees**

[image]

This also has the added benefit that it doesn't rely on the Image Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way, using the Image Processing Toolbox, is to use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html). Given an image:

```
>> img = reshape(1:25, 5, 5)
img =

    1    6   11   16   21
    2    7   12   17   22
    3    8   13   18   23
    4    9   14   19   24
    5   10   15   20   25
```

Then you can replicate the image on all sides:

```
>> padarray(img, size(img), 'circular')
ans =

    1    6   11   16   21  |  1    6   11   16   21  |  1    6   11   16   21
    2    7   12   17   22  |  2    7   12   17   22  |  2    7   12   17   22
    3    8   13   18   23  |  3    8   13   18   23  |  3    8   13   18   23
    4    9   14   19   24  |  4    9   14   19   24  |  4    9   14   19   24
    5   10   15   20   25  |  5   10   15   20   25  |  5   10   15   20   25
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1    6   11   16   21  |  1    6   11   16   21  |  1    6   11   16   21
    2    7   12   17   22  |  2    7   12   17   22  |  2    7   12   17   22
    3    8   13   18   23  |  3    8   13   18   23  |  3    8   13   18   23
    4    9   14   19   24  |  4    9   14   19   24  |  4    9   14   19   24
    5   10   15   20   25  |  5   10   15   20   25  |  5   10   15   20   25
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1    6   11   16   21  |  1    6   11   16   21  |  1    6   11   16   21
    2    7   12   17   22  |  2    7   12   17   22  |  2    7   12   17   22
    3    8   13   18   23  |  3    8   13   18   23  |  3    8   13   18   23
    4    9   14   19   24  |  4    9   14   19   24  |  4    9   14   19   24
    5   10   15   20   25  |  5   10   15   20   25  |  5   10   15   20   25
```

(Lines added to show the original matrix in the center and the padded copies.) Once you're done rotating, you can crop the middle of the matrix for your final image.

Note that this method also works on 3-channel images.

---

As @Suever and @BlackAdder note in the comments, this padding can be insufficient for images with large aspect ratio (greater than 25.456:9), particularly for rotations near odd multiples of 45°. You can make the padding more accurate by calculating the maximum you might need.

```
s = size(img);
s = s(1:2);                      % account for multi-channel images

maxext = sqrt(s * s.');          % calculate length of image diagonal
padsize = ceil((maxext - s)/2);  % find amount of padding needed for each side

padarray(img, padsize, 'circular');
```

Comment: This only works for certain aspect ratios (determines how many times you need to repeat your image). My answer above handles any arbitrary dimensions of the original image.

Comment: @Suever Please see the update and let me know if I've missed anything.